# Define a customized operation in MXNetR

Tags: python, r, neural-network, deep-learning, mxnet

I am creating a network using mxnetR and want to create a customized operator. I look at the mx.symbol.Custom function in the package and the description says that I should use a front end language like Python to define my operation.

I found a sample code here: https://github.com/dmlc/mxnet/issues/4205 where the programmer use the @mx.operator.register decorator followed by the definition of the operation. I wonder if I can do the same thing in R.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, current version of R package for MxNet doesn't support custom operators. You can create custom loss functions and custom metrics, but not operations for now. Stay tuned, it is probably going to change in future.